# Geb: Open new tab for each test

Tags: testing, groovy, automation, spock, geb

I am trying to open new tab for each iteration of the test  for each set of data in the where block.

I am trying like:

```
setup:
Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t")
```

but it does not work.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by this [WRITING AT THE BEGGINING OF THE TEST]:

```
def cachedDriver = CachingDriverFactory.clearCacheAndQuitDriver()
```

Now a new window is opened and previous window is closed for every set of data in the **where** block and it is very helpful for executing thousands of tests.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window using WebDriver and therefore Geb as well you need to call the `window.open()` javascript method in the browser you're driving. Using Geb it can be done in the following way:

`js.exec "window.open('about:blank', '', '')"`

Comment: I solved with 
def cachedDriver = CachingDriverFactory.clearCacheAndQuitDriver()